Cell In[8], line 2 model = CPCModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, context_size, prediction_steps) ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent
``import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision.transforms import Compose
from torchaudio.datasets import LIBRISPEECH
class LibriSpeechDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, split='train-clean-100', download=True, transform=None):
        self.dataset = LIBRISPEECH(root=root, url=split, download=download)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        waveform, sample_rate, label, speaker_id, chapter_id, utterance_id = self.dataset[idx]
        # Apply transformations if available
        if self.transform:
            waveform = self.transform(waveform)

        return waveform, label
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/hv/Desktop')
from librispeech_dataset import LibriSpeechDataset
import torch.nn.functional as F
class CPCModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, context_size, prediction_steps):
        super(CPCModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, context_size * prediction_steps)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x
def train_cpc_model(model, dataloader, criterion, optimizer, epochs=5):
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        running_loss = 0.0
        for batch_idx, (data, labels) in enumerate(dataloader):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(data)
            loss = criterion(output, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()
            if batch_idx % 100 == 99:  # Print every 100 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, batch_idx + 1, running_loss / 100))
                running_loss = 0.0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set up training parameters
    root = '/Users/harishvennakula/Desktop'  # Change this to the appropriate path
    batch_size = 32
    num_workers = 2
    epochs = 5
    lr = 0.001
    input_dim = 128  # Size of Mel spectrogram features
    hidden_dim = 512
    context_size = 10
    prediction_steps = 5
# Initialize model, criterion, optimizer, and data loader
    model = CPCModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, context_size, prediction_steps)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
import torchaudio.transforms as T
transform = Compose([
    T.MelSpectrogram(sample_rate=16000, n_fft=400, win_length=400, hop_length=160, n_mels=128),
    T.FrequencyMasking(freq_mask_param=30),
    T.TimeMasking(time_mask_param=100)
])
dataset = LibriSpeechDataset(root=root, download=True, transform=transform)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)
# Train the model
    train_cpc_model(model, dataloader, criterion, optimizer, epochs=epochs)`

Can anyone help with is error. I am trying to resolve this error but I am getting error again and again. I have created librispeech_dataset.py where it can read the librispeech dataset and I have given the path on the top at sys.path.append it is successfully loading the path for dataset. But when I am running model = cpc model part I am getting error.

You can't have a cell split in the middle of a block statement.

Is this what you're looking for? I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it? It's pretty broad and generic, but hopefully you'll at least get some background info there. If you need more specifics, please make a [mre] with minimal code, and be super clear about how to run it in IPython/Jupyter or whatever you're using.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. You can [edit] your post.
